# Get Matrix {field_row_count} when using the search parameter.

Tags: matrix, pixelandtonic

I have a Matrix field that I'm using the search parameter on. Within the output I need to grab the actual `{row_count}` associated with each row based on the order the row appears within the CP-based entry and not the order associated with the filtered results. It seems like the `{field_row_count}` variable should give me exactly what I need, but it's not working as expected.

Here's a simplified sample of the code:

```
{cf_project_images search:categories="{segment_category_ids_piped}" }
    <h2><a href="/portfolio/detail/{url_title}/{field_row_count}">{title}</a></h2>
{/cf_project_images}
```

As an example: The sample I'm testing has 4 rows within the Matrix field. Using the search parameter I'm only returning 1 of those 4 rows. If the row that is returned is the 4th row I would expect the value of `{field_row_count}` to be 4, but it's returning as 1.

Am I misinterpreting the way the `{field_row_count}` variable works?

Comment: What do you get in your example when using {field_total_rows}?

Comment: {field_total_rows} returns the value of the number of rows that the search parameter returns (which doesn't match the total number of rows in the original entry).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else that might stumble on this question, it turns out there was a bug in Matrix 2.5.10 that was impacting my specific issue. They've got a patch in place and it sounds like they'll be releasing an update soon.

Turns out `{field_row_count}` works exactly as I was expecting it to. Yip!

Answer (score 0):

Can you use {row_id} instead? I think the count you're getting is based on the way the search aspect works with the returned results.

Comment: {row_id} returns an ID unique to that row, but it looks like the number isn't related to the specific row within a given entry, which is what I need for this instance. Thanks though!